# Reading a row from a csv file using Unique ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I would really appreciate it if you guys could help with how i can read a row from a csv file using a unique purchasing ID inside that row with the csv module in python.
[This is the format my csv file is in](https://gyazo.com/7f9d19059ec668553947353779e3e505)

This is how i''m writing to the csv file (if it helps).

```
      userNames = input("What are the full names of the people you are ordering tickets for? ")
  localTime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()) )
  with open("Purchases.csv", "a") as f:
     f.write(f"\n{userNames}, {ticketList[0]}, {ticketList[1]}, {ticketList[2]}, {ticketList[3]}, {totalCost}, {localTime}, {uniqueID}\n")
     print(f"Fantasialand Ticket!")
```

This is where I need help to read the row with it's unique ID:

```
def searchingForFile():
  iUniqueID = int(input("What is the Unique ID of the past purchase?")
  with open("Purchases.csv", mode="rt", encoding='ascii') as f:
     spamreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     for row in spamreader :
        print(' '.join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

The uniqueID seems to be the last column in your CVS:

```
def searchingForFile():
  iUniqueID = int(input("What is the Unique ID of the past purchase?")
  with open("Purchases.csv", mode="rt", encoding='ascii') as f:
     spamreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     is_first_row = True
     for row in spamreader :
        print(' '.join(row))
        # if you have a header row
        if is_first_row:
          # skip if header
          is_first_row = False
        else:
          uid = int(row[-1])
          if uid == iUniqueID:
            return row
  return None
```

On a sidenote: I strongly recommend to use `csv.writer` (or csv.DictWriter) for writing the CSV file. It will take care of escaping, correct dialect etc.

Comment: Hi,When i try to do this, i get an error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: `row[-1:]` was wrong - correct is `row[-1]` without colon (I've corrected the code in the answer).

Comment: Hi, i'm now getting a new error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'UniqueID'

Comment: Because, obviously, your first row contains column headers which means that the string 'UniqueID' is input to the cast int(). Using csv.DictReader helps, or just skip the first row if you're sure that there is a header, otherwise check for a header.

Comment: @DeathResister I've added a check for the header though this has nothing to do with the problem in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if row contains that element,

```
def searchingForFile():
  iUniqueID = int(input("What is the Unique ID of the past purchase?")
  with open("Purchases.csv", mode="rt", encoding='ascii') as f:
     spamreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     for row in spamreader :
         if iUniqueID in row: 
             print(' '.join(row))
```

Or check for the value in a a particular cell:

```
def searchingForFile():
  iUniqueID = int(input("What is the Unique ID of the past purchase?")
  with open("Purchases.csv", mode="rt", encoding='ascii') as f:
     spamreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     for row in spamreader :
         if iUniqueID == row[-1]: 
             print(' '.join(row))
```

Comment: The row items will be strings, so without conversion the checks will always be False.

Comment: Hi, when i try to either of these, i  don't get any row printed out